# How do I make pip aware of a Python package (python3-wxPython), which has been installed using zypper?

Tags: opensuse, pip

I've got Python 3.11 installed on my OpenSuSE 15.5 machine together with `python3-wxPython-4.1.1-150400.3.3.1.x86_64` for wxWidget bindings. Now I'd like to install `DisplayCAL`, which does not come in RPM format, so I have to use `pip`. Now I'm running into a strange issue: `DisplayCAL` does get built, but `pip` also triggers an installation of `wxPython` (although it's already been installed!) and fails to build it due to a missing file in the tarball. So I end up without `DisplayCAL` (which finally does not get installed due to the `wxPython` build failure).

So: How can I tell `pip` that `wxPython` has already been installed, albeit not by using pip, so that it stops trying re-installing `wxPython`? Is there any possibility to edit the `pip` database of installed packages manually? **OR:** Ist it possible to circumvent the `wxPython` requirement in the project metadata of `DisplayCAL`?